# Python:Coinmarketcap API down?

Tags: python, json, api, streaming, cryptocurrency

I've been using the Coinmarketcap Api `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/` for a couple of weeks. It was the only API I found that sent almost live data (every 130s) in a `.json` format for free!

But now it seems like it's down. Does anyone have an alternative for me?

**UPDATE--FOUND ONE:**

https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to use v1 of the CoinMarketCap API. That version was deprecated and disabled a while back. You need to use v2 of their API which now requires an API key for access and has a slightly different format.